# How to return the maximum value in a string of alphanumerical characters (eg-1A003B3)?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, c++11

Consider for example , the input is 1A003B3 . In this case the program must return 66,i.e.,the ASCII value of B.

I have tried this way but not getting the right output.

```
for(int d=0;d<str.length();d++)
                    {
                        if(str[d]>max)
                        max=str[d];
                    }
```

Comment: This part looks correct, the problem is probably somewhere else. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `max = *std::max_element(str.begin(), str.end());`  (won't work for an empty string; figure out what you want to do in that case).

Comment: The code shown doesn't produce any output, whether right or wrong. To the extent there is a problem, it likely likes in the code not shown.

Comment: Well, even the declaration of variable `max` is not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard algorithm `std::max_element`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "1A003B3" );

    auto it = std::max_element( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ),
                                []( char c1, char c2 )
                                {
                                    return ( unsigned char )c1 < ( unsigned char )c2;
                                } );

    std::cout << "The maximum value is " 
              << static_cast<int>( static_cast<unsigned char>( *it ) ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The maximum value is 66
```

As for your code snippet then it should look the following way

```
unsigned char max = ( unsigned char )str[0];

for( std::string::size_type i = 1; i < str.length(); i++ )
{
    if ( max < ( unsigned char )str[i] ) max = ( unsigned char )str[i];
}
```

And to output the value use the expression

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>( max ) << '\n';
```